# How to get the children class text using function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to get the children class text. I am creating a div element dynamically at runtime like below

```
<%
foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~/CrystalReportFiles/")).GetDirectories())
{ %>
    <div class="MainFolder <%= dir.Name %>" onclick="someFunction(this,'<%= dir.Name %>')"  style="padding-left: 20px; ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span><%= dir.Name %><br />

        <% var filepath = "~/CrystalReportFiles/" + dir.Name + "/"; %>
        <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue"><% =filepath %></span>
    </div>
<br />
<%}%>
```

So in the browser it will be like this

```
<div class="MainFolder Great Plains" onclick="someFunction(this,'Great Plains')" style="padding-left: 20px; ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Great Plains<br>

    <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/CrystalReportFiles/Great Plains/</span>
</div>

<div class="MainFolder Microsoft" onclick="someFunction(this,'Microsoft')" style="padding-left: 20px; ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Microsoft<br>

    <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/CrystalReportFiles/Microsoft/</span>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the respective `.pathValue` text when the user clicks.

If the user clicks `MainFolder Great Plains`, I want to get `~/CrystalReportFiles/Great Plains/` text,

If the user clicks `MainFolder Microsoft`, I want to get `~/CrystalReportFiles/Microsoft/` text,

I tried the following Jquery code:

```
// when the user clicks Microsoft
function someFunction(obj, abc) {
    alert(abc);     //Microsoft
    var classname = abc;
    alert(obj.getAttribute('class'));  //MainFolder Microsoft

    var $self = obj.getAttribute('class')
    alert("classname = " + classname);
    alert($("'." + classname + "'").children('.pathValue').text()); //error

}
```

Comment: You can use `$("'." + classname + "'").find('.pathValue')`

Comment: @TanDuong no it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same input in both onclick event

`onclick="someFunction(this,'Great Plains')"`

I think it should be `Microsoft` in second onclick event.

Since you have pass `this` as a variable, we can get the text by using `obj`.

```js
function someFunction(obj, abc) {
  var text = $(obj).find('.pathValue').text()
  console.log(text)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MainFolder Great Plains" onclick="someFunction(this,'Great Plains')" style="padding-left: 20px; ">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Great Plains<br>

  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/CrystalReportFiles/Great Plains/</span>
</div>

<div class="MainFolder Microsoft" onclick="someFunction(this,'Great Plains')" style="padding-left: 20px; ">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Microsoft<br>

  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/CrystalReportFiles/Microsoft/</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is correct, can I call ajax through this function?

Comment: Definitely yes.